# How to get the position of a row in an arbitrary ordering?

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I'm paginating my SQL results (10 per page). I want to find out on which page a given row (`id` known via URL) would be, so that I can jump to the correct page directly.

The ordering is known, but it's not a simple `ORDER BY id ASC`, so I can't just count the rows `id < wanted_id`.

MySQL-specific commands and subqueries are permitted. I want to **avoid variables**.

Any approaches?

#### EDIT to make myself clear...

I am capable of getting the results. What I need is the *rank* (i.e. the number of rows that would be *before* that row) of that row. I'm not looking for brute-force approaches (I would rather retrieve 10k ids and find that rank programmatically).

Comment: Looks like below answers are executing the query in full, find out the page number & then retrieve it. I think the question intends to avoid the full query execution which is the first reason to use paging. Marcel, please clarify if that's not intended.

Comment: @isobar Clarified. Had assumed the headline was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the query and insert the result set into a temporary table. The temp should have, among other things, a dedicated auto increment column.

Find the value of the auto-increment column where the row contains the id in question, perform some simple arithmetics to calculate the page the row belongs to, and give out the page.

Comment: That could work but I think I would rather `SELECT(id)` and just find the index in the array. Seems to be more efficient on MEM/CPU.

Comment: @Marcel Jackwerth: I was thinking about a similar way until I realised that you would have to duplicate the search logic. That is, if I understood you correctly, you would have to use the same logic twice: first time when detecting the page, and second time when selecting all the data for the page.

Comment: Anyway, I'm far from insisting that my approach is best.

Comment: And just to make it clear: I was meaning all the operations to be parts of a single (multi-statement) query, so in the end the client side would only receive the page's rows, not the entire result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second Query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...`. In the WHERE clause, narrow the selected records down to the ones that come before the record in question.

Comment: @MarcelJackwerth I cannot help you with that, because I do not know the expression that you use to order the records.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, 
_rowid, 
floor (_rowid / 10)  
from table
```

Sorry, missed the "no variables" requirement.

You can use "limit" to jump to the specific page.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without variables - especially since that approach won't be better than retrieving all the `id`s and search for it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as rank_number
from my_table
order by c1, c2 desc
where 
    c1 <= (select c1 from my_table where id = @id)
    and
    c2 >= (select c2 from my_table where id = @id)
```